# entity framework 6.1 Seed & OnModelCreating not working together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using EF in a Web API project with code first mode.
So far, so good, but I have Time field in a table, where I want Precision 0.
So I added the required codes in the `OnModelCreating` method of the `DBContext` class.
after that the Seed method in Configuration class was not executed.
when I comment the code in `OnModelCreating`, the Seed method is executing.

I would be happy if somebody could give me a reason for this, and how shall I restructure my classes to run both of the methods.

Normally I use the standard way. I have the simplest DbContext:

```
public partial class HarmoniaContext : DbContext {
public HarmoniaContext()
  : base("Harmonia") {
}

...virtual properties or the DbSet<>...

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  modelBuilder.Entity<Nyitvatartas>()
      .Property(e => e.KezdIdo)
      .HasPrecision(0);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Nyitvatartas>()
      .Property(e => e.BefIdo)
      .HasPrecision(0);
}
}
```

and the configuration file

```
internal sealed class Configuration :DbMigrationsConfiguration<HarmoniaContext> {
public Configuration() {
  AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
}

protected override void Seed(HarmoniaContext context) {
  context.Beallitas.AddOrUpdate(b => b.Nev, ...}
  context.Szerepkor.AddOrUpdate(sz=> sz.RendszerNev, ...}

}
}
```

Comment: a skeleton of your :DbContext class with involved code (OnModelCreating and Initializer Seed) may help us.

Comment: Don't use "EDIT" in your posts; this is not a forum.  If you're having difficulty with your grammar and punctuation in the editor provided, use a word processor to check your grammar and punctuation for you before posting.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the content of your `OnModelCreating` and your `Seed`?